# Sort List except one entry with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I want to order a List of strings but one string in the list should always be at the beginning and not sorted. What is the easiest way to do this with LINQ?

```
//should be ordered in: first, a,b,u,z:
List<string> l = {"z","u","first","b","a"};
```

There is no prepend method or something in LINQ, is there?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
l = l.OrderBy(i => i != "first").ThenBy(i => i).ToList();
```

The trick here is to order by whether the item in question is your special item, then order by your item as you normally would.

Since you said you want to order a list (with linq) don't forget to assign the result of the query back to the list.

---

You also asked about a prepend method, how about this:

```
l = new[] { "first" }.Concat(l).ToList();
```

You could easily make it an extension method:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> query, T item)
    {
        return new[] { item }.Concat(query);
    }
}
```

called as:

```
l = l.Prepend("first").ToList();
```

Comment: `i != "first"` make me smile `:)`

Comment: how about , if we have 2 or more entries to exempt?

Comment: @IvanMatala: `!new [] {"first", "2"}.Contains(i)`

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett, great! I just did not understand how `OrderBy(i => i != "first")` puts "first" to the beginning of the list. Would you mind to explain it?

Comment: @Marcello the expression evaluates to false for the item we want first and true for all other items. Ordering by a boolean has the false value (our item) first then the true value (all others) after.

Comment: You are awesome.. Most interesting answer till now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `OrderBy`, `ThenBy` pattern:

```
string[] l = { "z", "u", "first", "b", "a" };

var result = l.OrderBy(i => i != "first").ThenBy(i => i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Order by two criteria. The first criteria is based on some sort of predicate, the second on the value of the items:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var list = new[] { "z", "u", "first", "b", "a" }.OrderByPredicateFirst(s => s == "first").ToList();
    Assert.AreEqual("first", list[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual("a", list[1]);
    Assert.AreEqual("b", list[2]);
    Assert.AreEqual("u", list[3]);
    Assert.AreEqual("z", list[4]);
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderByPredicateFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Predicate<T> firsts)
    {
        return source
          .OrderBy(s => firsts(s) ? 0 : 1)
          .ThenBy(s => s);
    }
}
```